# How to do call a smart contract at intervals on the matic network?

Tags: solidity, events, chainlink, defi

I'm trying to write a smart contract to farm tokens.  I would like to make an auto-compounding solution similar to beefy.finance or polycats.

My contract can deposit funds or liquidity into LP mining, and I can autocompound them fine off chain from the backend.  However doing something like this would make my solution centralized, and I was hoping to avoid that.

What I want is to call a method at intervals on my smart contract.  I think there used be something for the main-net called ethereum-alarm-clock but I've heard the project is dead.

How can I distribute rewards in a decentralized fashion?

I'm open to external protocol such as using an oracle like chain link, but I would prefer to decentralize earning so I do not need to host a backend service.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chainlink Keepers is the perfect solution for your use case. They are a decentralized network of off-chain nodes that are incentivized to perform all registered jobs (upkeeps) off chain in a decentralized and trust minimized manner, and can be triggered based upon any pre-configured conditions (such as time or event based conditions).

By using an off-chain decentralized service such as Chainlink Keepers, you extend the security and decentralization properties that the blockchain has out to the off-chain compute layer, instead of relying on a centralized solution such as a service or single node triggering your function

Check out the [docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/), as well as a recent [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtFiIqLYVlA) for a good guide on getting your on-chain contract setup to be Keepers-compatible, as well as how to then register your upkeep job on the [Keepers Registry](https://keepers.chain.link/)

Comment: Wow, I took a guess when I said chain link since I knew they provided external data but this looks promising.  By chance do you have a short code example?  If not I'll scour the docs and video and try to edit the answer so that it has the information needed

Comment: There's an example contract here that the keeper network will automatically call the performUpkeep function based off a time parameter passed into the contract. So if you pass in 30 seconds, then it will get triggered every 30 seconds https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using chainlink keepers.  To Summary a simple example from the [docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/)

You can create a keeper compatible contract such as this counter:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/KeeperCompatible.sol";

contract Counter is KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    uint public counter;

    uint public immutable interval;
    uint public lastTimeStamp;

    constructor(uint updateInterval) {
    interval = updateInterval;
    lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;

    counter = 0;
    }

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */) external override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
        // We don't use the checkData in this example. The checkData is defined when the Upkeep was registered.
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        counter = counter + 1;
        // We don't use the performData in this example. The performData is generated by the Keeper's call to your checkUpkeep function
    }
}
```

Then we just need to register the keeper with the appropriate keepers for the network in my case [mumbai keeper](https://keepers.chain.link/mumbai)